# "I George Brent myself" meaning

Tags: reference, family-guy

In Family Guy, season 16, episode 7, Putin is entering Peter's house and declaring he needs the bathroom because he "George Brent himself". I have googled this, as instructed by Peter, but could not find out what it means. What does it mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a reference to hall-of-fame baseball player George Brett.

https://deadspin.com/george-brett-would-like-to-tell-you-about-that-time-he-5052185

It's basically a reference to defecating in one's pants.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=George%20Brett), it means:

> Having uncontrollable watery diarrhea that runs down the back of your leg, usually after eating bad shellfish or possibly Mexican food.
>
> *I pulled a George Brett on my drive home from Red Lobster and shit all over my car.*

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Movies & TV. This doesn't bring anything new to the accepted answer. Can you please either elaborate or clarify?